# Using subliminal, mode of operation & supported type of tests

Tags: subliminal

I am evaluating test suites and have few Qs regarding subliminal

1. Is this a stand-alone tool, OR, does it mandate X-code to be installed ?
2. While having x-code installed, can subliminal run seperately, OR, does it integrate into X-code IDE?
3. Technically speaking, For automated & scheduled testing, having subliminal code @ github, can a tool be implemented to execute tests out of the x-code IDE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subliminal works with Apple's developer tools, both Xcode and Instruments in particular.  You'll need to install those tools for Subliminal tests to work.  You don't need to run the Xcode application itself to run Subliminal tests; you can run them from the command line using the convenience script [subliminal-test](https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/wiki/Continuous-Integration).  So:

1. Xcode (and Apple's developer tools in general) must be installed.
2. Subliminal tests can be run without the Xcode app itself running, but they rely on Xcode and Instruments (and usually the iOS simulator).
3. Tests can be executed outside of the Xcode app, but not entirely independently of the developer tools.  The tool you should use for running scheduled tests is [subliminal-test](https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/wiki/Continuous-Integration).

Comment: Should the application being instrumented be compiled in any special way? OR, Can it be used to test an app published on the AppStore ( after it was downloaded to my local iPhone ) ?

Comment: @NadavRub Typically you run Subliminal integration tests using an application target in an Xcode project, and that target is a duplicate of the application you're testing with the addition of the Subliminal test code.  See: https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/wiki/Create-the-Integration-Tests-Target.  Subliminal does not currently support attaching to and testing pre-built binaries.